# JavaScript Objects and constructor types

Tags: javascript, object, collections, constructor

**Recreate the same type of object**

As per the Image Im trying to recreat that type of Object . Chrome Dev tools

`Console.log(TabPanel)`
Gives me the return on the object but what I don't understand is how the function name

> TabPanel : *f* TabPanel()

follows the *f* symbol in the log .

How can I recreate that type of object with a simple example I have tried to use constructors and prototypes . I'm not sure how they achieved this

[the console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqb7X.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What devtools is showing you there is that the value of `TabPanel` property on the object you logged is a reference to a function called `TabPanel` (not an object created by `TabPanel`, the `TabPanel` function itself). Here's an example:

```js
function Example() {
}
var o = {
  ex: Example
};
console.log(o);
```

```html
Look in the real console.
```

That gives us:

[image]

Comment: Oooohhhhhhhhh Thanks that makes sense....

Would up vote you if i could

Answer (score 1):

If you create your function with a name, then it will display like that in your console.

```
const TabPanel = function TabPanel() {};
console.log(TabPanel);
```

Will log as you show in your screenshot

If you wanted this as part of an object, you could do:

```
const TabPanel = {
    TabPanel: function TabPanel() { ... }
}
```

Which would log as an object, which when expanded would show you your named function.

Comment: Thank you but place that in an object like 
'TabPanel = {};
TabPanel .TabPanel  = (function(){....}); '

you still dont see it like that in chrome log

Comment: Yes, by defining a function without a name, it won't show as you desire, because the function has no name. Updated my example